# Setting session variable as a number then checking isset against that variable number

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have created a simple PHP login system, I am fairly new to PHP in some ways. The login system doesn't use a database as its only one user.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
{
 die("You are already logged in!");
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if ($_POST["Username"]=="****" && $_POST["password"]=="****")
{
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = "1";
print $_SESSION['loggedin'];
} 
}
?>
```

Then for every other page I have a PHP checker with an if statement:

```
<?php
session_start(); // NEVER forget this!
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'] = "1"))
{
die("To access this page, you need to <a href='login.php'>LOGIN</a>");
} 
?>
```

It worked when I just set loggedin to 'YES' and then used the line

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
```

But when I try to assign loggedin a number in this example 1, and then make the checker check that if its NOT the number 1 then die, like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'] = "1"))
```

it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using == instead of =. Using '=' will assign the value 1 to the session variable.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'] == "1"))
```

However, a better option would be:

```
if($_SESSION['loggedin'] != "1")
```

Using [Yoda conditions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) and checking whether $_SESSION['loggedin'] is set, that would be:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || "1" != $_SESSION['loggedin'])
```

Comment: use ("1"==$_SESSION['loggedin']) instead of ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == "1")

Comment: Yoda conditions! http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html  :D

Answer (score 1):

```
if( !isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] != "1" )
```

Also make sure that you have session_start() at the top of your first example.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
{
    die("You are already logged in!");
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if ($_POST["Username"]=="****" && $_POST["password"]=="****")
    {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "1";
        print $_SESSION['loggedin'];
    } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a String as a value, you can also use the php function `strcmp($str1, $str2)` for binary safe string comparison. So you may do this test:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && strcmp($_SESSION['loggedin'], '1') == 0)
```

If the values on `strcmp` are equal, it evaluates to 0. If `str1` is less than `str2` it returns < 0 and if `str1` is greater than `str2` it returns > 0.

For more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php